# Is there any GitHub pull-request dataset with labels information?

Tags: data-request, metadata

I also tried to get the labels for a pull-request using GitHub API, but that did not work as labels are not linked with the pull-request. Any idea? How can I get the PR comments labels for GitHub repositories?